# SAS- PROC UNIVARIATE > histogram > x axis values

Tags: sas, histogram

I have a single continuous variable with highly skewed distribution. I have log transformed it for normalization. while creating a histogram of the variable with PROC UNIVARIATE (SAS 9.3), is there a way by which I can plot the transformed variable, but keep the values of original variable on x axis ?

if this topic has been already discussed then, I would really appreciate if someone can provide a link. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SAS Graph Template Language (GTL) to do this.  The documentation contains plenty of examples that you should be able to change and modify to your needs.  The output from PROC UNIVARIATE is produced by the GTL so you should be able to generate something similar.

Take the output dataset from proc univariate and base the plot off that.  You will need to reverse the transformations first.

Documentation for the GTL:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatgraph/65377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1sxw5gidyzrygn1ibkzfmc5c93m.htm